# Quiero crear una función que me lea un excel, crear un diccionario(clave:centros_salud, valor:distrito) y que devuelva las claves con valores comunes

Tags: python

Me he quedado atascada en el recorrido del diccionario pero no sé cómo sacar las claves con valores comunes.

Por ejemplo: Villaverde (valor)-centro_salud 1, centro_salud 2, centro_salud 3, centro_salud 4, centro_salud 5 y centro_salud 6 (claves).

```
import pandas as pd

xls=pd.ExcelFile("C_salud_distritos.xls")
df=xls.parse("C_salud_distritos")
print(df)

diccionario=dict(df.values)
print(diccionario)

for clave,valor in diccionario.items():
    print(clave,valor)
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar, muchas gracias.

Comment: Me he quedado atascada en el recorrido del diccionario pero no sé cómo sacar las claves con valores comunes. Por ejemplo: Villaverde (valor)-centro_salud 1, centro_salud 2, centro_salud 3, centro_salud 4, centro_salud 5 y centro_salud 6 (claves). Si alguien me puede ayudar, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenida Mar c: Aquí tienes una forma de lograr lo que buscas!

```
# creo un diccionario con los datos (para probar)
diccionario = {"centro_salud1":"villa verde",
               "centro_salud2":"villa verde",
               "centro_salud3":"villa verde",
               "centro_salud4":"villa verde",
               "centro_salud5":"villa roja",
               "centro_salud6":"villa roja"}
diccionario2 = {}

for key, value in diccionario.items():
    #si el valor no está en el diccionario, agrego el par "value:lista vacia".
    if(value not in diccionario2):
        diccionario2[value]=[]

    # Agrego la clave a la lista
    diccionario2[value].append(key)

print(diccionario2)
```